# A 'Child Genius' vs. a 'Genius Child'

Tags: adjectives, word-order

I watched a [video on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bGqvimnOTeg). Its title was:

> Is Andy Smarter Than a Child Genius?

I think it should be: Is Andy Smarter Than a **Genius Child**?

So, why the adjective comes after the noun "Child"?

Will that make a difference in meaning?

Comment: There is no adjective in the phrase: *genius* and *child* are both nouns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the order of the words changes the emphasis. "Genius Child" means "a child who is a genius" and could imply that the child is smart relative to other children. "Child Genius" means "a genius who is a child" and could imply that the child is smart relative to most other people, adults included.

Comment: Superficially this seems "logical", but I don't think many native speakers would apprehend the somewhat contrived distinction. The main thing they'd be likely to think on hearing *My son is a **genius child*** is just that the speaker isn't a native Anglophone.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I would disagree. They may not think through the distinction, but native speakers are well accustomed to the order and precedence of nouns and adjectives, and would 'sense' the distinction in speech.

Answer (score 2):

As [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=was%20a%20genius%20child%2Cwas%20a%20child%20genius&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwas%20a%20child%20genius%3B%2Cc0) shows, it's always ***child genius***, never ***genius child***...

[image]

As [@StoneyB comments](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/108434/a-child-genius-vs-a-genius-child#comment217359_108434), strictly speaking both ***genius*** and ***child*** are *nouns*. In principle, either could be used adjectivally (as a [noun adjunct, attributive noun, noun premodifier, converted adjective](http://grammar.about.com/od/ab/g/Attributive-Noun.htm)).

But in practice we rarely if ever use ***genius*** adjectivally, whereas combinations like *[a child ticket](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a%20child%20ticket%22), [a child seat](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a%20child%20seat%22), [a child prodigy](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a%20child%20prodigy%22)* are well-established idiomatic usages. That's why we prefer ***child genius***.